# How to run spring boot application on Spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

We have generated a Jar of Spark java spring boot Application.

```
        ./spark-submit --class com.recordlinkage.coreTest.IntegratedRecordLinkageTest 
                --deploy-mode cluster 
                --master spark://UCSL-GKL-HDP-02:6066/home/hadoop/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/AIRecordLinkage.jar
```

**It runs without errors in eclipse in the system we developed it**, before exporting it to jar.
while trying to run it on a cluster mode using standalone spark submit function , we are facing issue.
We are suspecting spring variables like autowired are not in context, hence objects are not constructed.
        Therefore we are getting nullpointer exception

```
        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper$.main(DriverWrapper.scala:58)
                at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper.main(DriverWrapper.scala)
```

We are running it on test class,here is the code below

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest
    public class IntegratedRecordLinkageTest {
     @Autowired
     private LoadCSV loadCSV;

     @Autowired
     private Environment envirnoment;

     @Autowired
     private IntegratedRecordLinkage integratedRecordLinkage;


     @Test
     public void testLoadCSVFile() {

      try{   
       integratedRecordLinkage.link();
      }
      catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
       Assert.fail("Exception Occurred");
      }
     }
    }
```

kindly let us know how to run spring boot application on cluster

Answer (score 2):

It is awkward to run things "in real life" via a test. The Maven configuration model--used by many build tools besides Maven itself--assumes code and configuration to be in different places depending on the scope--compile, runtime, test, etc. Running a test at runtime scope doesn't make a lot of sense to me. It's fine to try something unorthodox, but your current setup seems to be a lot more trouble than it's worth.

Instead, I would run things the way you are supposed to:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class AIRecordLinkage implements CommandLineRunner {

  @Autowired
  private LoadCSV loadCSV;

   @Autowired
   private Environment environment;

   @Autowired
   private IntegratedRecordLinkage integratedRecordLinkage;


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AIRecordLinkage.class, args);
  }

  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    integratedRecordLinkage.link();
  }
}
```

Comment: We tried the above method, But still getting the NullPointer exeption. we are unable to identify the cause of exception due to lack of information in log .can u give a more clue on handling this issue. If u can provide any link or documentation on deploying a Springboot application it will be helpful